# Solr boolean queries combined with index-time boosts

Tags: solr

I have a site using Solr 1.4.1 for relevancy/recommendations. I am using boolean-style queries in some places. I am using a query like `+(+type:aoh_company +aoh_dictionary_tids:623)` - and that provides the expected results, but the order of the results appear to be arbitrary.

I am trying to control the ranking of the document by setting index-time boosts, but they seem to be ignored for these queries.

### An example

- The query URL is `http://localhost:4930/solr/prod/select?rows=5&start=0&q.alt=(type%3Aaoh_company)+(aoh_dictionary_tids%3A623)&q=`
- The results are returned in this order (with the index time boost value in parentheses):

  1. 17132 (1.22)
  2. 17179 (1.02)
  3. 17131 (1.10)
  4. 17133 (1.10)
  5. 17184 (1.10)
- Obviously, result #2 should not come before #3-5 based on the boost alone.
- Given this is a boolean query, there should not be much difference in ranking.

#### Debugging output

I tried debugging the query above by appending `debugQuery=true` to the query, so it becomes `http://localhost:4930/solr/prod/select?rows=5&start=0&q.alt=(type%3Aaoh_company)+(aoh_dictionary_tids%3A623)&q=&debugQuery=true`

It's very verbose, but here it is:

```
<lst name="debug">
  <null name="rawquerystring"/>
  <null name="querystring"/>
  <str name="parsedquery">+(+type:aoh_company +aoh_dictionary_tids:623)</str>
  <str name="parsedquery_toString">+(+type:aoh_company +aoh_dictionary_tids:623)</str>
  <lst name="explain">
    <str name="50hves/node/17132">
    1.7819747 = (MATCH) sum of:
      0.9014403 = (MATCH) weight(type:aoh_company in 1805), product of:
        0.37135038 = queryWeight(type:aoh_company), product of:
          2.4274657 = idf(docFreq=457, maxDocs=1909)
          0.15297863 = queryNorm
        2.4274657 = (MATCH) fieldWeight(type:aoh_company in 1805), product of:
          1.0 = tf(termFreq(type:aoh_company)=1)
          2.4274657 = idf(docFreq=457, maxDocs=1909)
          1.0 = fieldNorm(field=type, doc=1805)
      0.88053435 = (MATCH) weight(aoh_dictionary_tids:623 in 1805), product of:
        0.9284928 = queryWeight(aoh_dictionary_tids:623), product of:
          6.069428 = idf(docFreq=11, maxDocs=1909)
          0.15297863 = queryNorm
        0.9483481 = (MATCH) fieldWeight(aoh_dictionary_tids:623 in 1805), product of:
          1.0 = tf(termFreq(aoh_dictionary_tids:623)=1)
          6.069428 = idf(docFreq=11, maxDocs=1909)
          0.15625 = fieldNorm(field=aoh_dictionary_tids, doc=1805)
    </str>
    <str name="50hves/node/17179">
    1.7819747 = (MATCH) sum of:
      0.9014403 = (MATCH) weight(type:aoh_company in 1896), product of:
        0.37135038 = queryWeight(type:aoh_company), product of:
          2.4274657 = idf(docFreq=457, maxDocs=1909)
          0.15297863 = queryNorm
        2.4274657 = (MATCH) fieldWeight(type:aoh_company in 1896), product of:
          1.0 = tf(termFreq(type:aoh_company)=1)
          2.4274657 = idf(docFreq=457, maxDocs=1909)
          1.0 = fieldNorm(field=type, doc=1896)
      0.88053435 = (MATCH) weight(aoh_dictionary_tids:623 in 1896), product of:
        0.9284928 = queryWeight(aoh_dictionary_tids:623), product of:
          6.069428 = idf(docFreq=11, maxDocs=1909)
          0.15297863 = queryNorm
        0.9483481 = (MATCH) fieldWeight(aoh_dictionary_tids:623 in 1896), product of:
          1.0 = tf(termFreq(aoh_dictionary_tids:623)=1)
          6.069428 = idf(docFreq=11, maxDocs=1909)
          0.15625 = fieldNorm(field=aoh_dictionary_tids, doc=1896)
    </str>
    <str name="50hves/node/17131">
    1.7819747 = (MATCH) sum of:
      0.9014403 = (MATCH) weight(type:aoh_company in 1905), product of:
        0.37135038 = queryWeight(type:aoh_company), product of:
          2.4274657 = idf(docFreq=457, maxDocs=1909)
          0.15297863 = queryNorm
        2.4274657 = (MATCH) fieldWeight(type:aoh_company in 1905), product of:
          1.0 = tf(termFreq(type:aoh_company)=1)
          2.4274657 = idf(docFreq=457, maxDocs=1909)
          1.0 = fieldNorm(field=type, doc=1905)
      0.88053435 = (MATCH) weight(aoh_dictionary_tids:623 in 1905), product of:
        0.9284928 = queryWeight(aoh_dictionary_tids:623), product of:
          6.069428 = idf(docFreq=11, maxDocs=1909)
          0.15297863 = queryNorm
        0.9483481 = (MATCH) fieldWeight(aoh_dictionary_tids:623 in 1905), product of:
          1.0 = tf(termFreq(aoh_dictionary_tids:623)=1)
          6.069428 = idf(docFreq=11, maxDocs=1909)
          0.15625 = fieldNorm(field=aoh_dictionary_tids, doc=1905)
    </str>
    <str name="50hves/node/17133">
    1.7819747 = (MATCH) sum of:
      0.9014403 = (MATCH) weight(type:aoh_company in 1906), product of:
        0.37135038 = queryWeight(type:aoh_company), product of:
          2.4274657 = idf(docFreq=457, maxDocs=1909)
          0.15297863 = queryNorm
        2.4274657 = (MATCH) fieldWeight(type:aoh_company in 1906), product of:
          1.0 = tf(termFreq(type:aoh_company)=1)
          2.4274657 = idf(docFreq=457, maxDocs=1909)
          1.0 = fieldNorm(field=type, doc=1906)
      0.88053435 = (MATCH) weight(aoh_dictionary_tids:623 in 1906), product of:
        0.9284928 = queryWeight(aoh_dictionary_tids:623), product of:
          6.069428 = idf(docFreq=11, maxDocs=1909)
          0.15297863 = queryNorm
        0.9483481 = (MATCH) fieldWeight(aoh_dictionary_tids:623 in 1906), product of:
          1.0 = tf(termFreq(aoh_dictionary_tids:623)=1)
          6.069428 = idf(docFreq=11, maxDocs=1909)
          0.15625 = fieldNorm(field=aoh_dictionary_tids, doc=1906)
    </str>
    <str name="50hves/node/17184">
    1.6058679 = (MATCH) sum of:
      0.9014403 = (MATCH) weight(type:aoh_company in 1892), product of:
        0.37135038 = queryWeight(type:aoh_company), product of:
          2.4274657 = idf(docFreq=457, maxDocs=1909)
          0.15297863 = queryNorm
        2.4274657 = (MATCH) fieldWeight(type:aoh_company in 1892), product of:
          1.0 = tf(termFreq(type:aoh_company)=1)
          2.4274657 = idf(docFreq=457, maxDocs=1909)
          1.0 = fieldNorm(field=type, doc=1892)
      0.7044275 = (MATCH) weight(aoh_dictionary_tids:623 in 1892), product of:
        0.9284928 = queryWeight(aoh_dictionary_tids:623), product of:
          6.069428 = idf(docFreq=11, maxDocs=1909)
          0.15297863 = queryNorm
        0.7586785 = (MATCH) fieldWeight(aoh_dictionary_tids:623 in 1892), product of:
          1.0 = tf(termFreq(aoh_dictionary_tids:623)=1)
          6.069428 = idf(docFreq=11, maxDocs=1909)
          0.125 = fieldNorm(field=aoh_dictionary_tids, doc=1892)
    </str>
  </lst>
  <str name="QParser">DisMaxQParser</str>
  <str name="altquerystring">org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery:+type:aoh_company +aoh_dictionary_tids:623</str>
  <null name="boostfuncs"/>
  <lst name="timing">
    <double name="time">7.0</double>
    <lst name="prepare">
      <double name="time">1.0</double>
      <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent">
        <double name="time">0.0</double>
      </lst>
      <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.FacetComponent">
      <double name="time">0.0</double>
    </lst>
    <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.MoreLikeThisComponent">
    <double name="time">0.0</double>
  </lst>
  <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.HighlightComponent">
    <double name="time">0.0</double>
  </lst>
  <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.StatsComponent">
    <double name="time">0.0</double>
  </lst>
  <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent">
    <double name="time">0.0</double>
  </lst>
  <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.DebugComponent">
    <double name="time">0.0</double>
  </lst>
  </lst>
  <lst name="process">
    <double name="time">6.0</double>
    <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent">
      <double name="time">0.0</double>
    </lst>
    <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.FacetComponent">
      <double name="time">0.0</double>
    </lst>
    <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.MoreLikeThisComponent">
      <double name="time">0.0</double>
    </lst>
    <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.HighlightComponent">
      <double name="time">0.0</double>
    </lst>
    <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.StatsComponent">
      <double name="time">0.0</double>
    </lst>
    <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent">
      <double name="time">0.0</double>
    </lst>
    <lst name="org.apache.solr.handler.component.DebugComponent">
      <double name="time">6.0</double>
    </lst>
  </lst>
</lst>
```

As I read it, the first four results are scored `1.7819747`, and the fifth is scored `1.6058679`, and I can't see the boost values anywhere in there, so it seems that they are not a factor in the ranking equation.

So what am I doing wrong. Is there something I need to do to make Solr take the boosts into consideration?
Is there a way to check the boost value stored in Solr? It looks right in the documents I send to it, but I can't find a way to see the stored value?

Additionally, here's the relevant parts from my `schema.xml`:

```
<types>
  <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
  <fieldType name="integer" class="solr.IntField" omitNorms="true"/>
</types>
<fields>
  <field name="type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="aoh_dictionary_tids"  type="integer" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" omitNorms="false"/>
</fields>
```

In his answer below, fyr mentioned that norms need to be enabled on the field for the boost value to apply. So I'd like to amend my question a bit:

- Is it enough to have norms enabled on one of the queried fields for the boost to apply?
- Does my `omitNorms="false"` on the field override the `omitNorms="true"` on the fieldType?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will not see the boost in the explain. Boosting at indexing time is applied to the Norms of a certain field in a certain document. Like a multiplicator.

If you have Norms enabled your bosst value is used at indexing time. Norms are always part of the similarity function if you use the DefaultSimilarity and Norms are enabled.

Edit for the follow up questions:

1. It is enough to have norms enabled for the boost to apply. Because norms provide the field in the index with a data weight structure in the index. And index time boosts are multiplied on the norm value and saved to the norm field.
2. omitNorms on the field declaration overrides the type definition - You see this also on your explain structure. aoh_dictionary has a value which does not equal 1. If norms are disabled 1 is as default applied.

Comment: The boost is applied to the whole document. Norms are field-specific, right?

Comment: Exactly the boost at indexing time is document specific. But it is only applied to fields inside the document which have norms enabled. So if you have two Fields A(with norms) and B(without norms) and you query only B you will not notice any difference.

Comment: As addition this depends a little bit on your solr library if you have the possibility to set also field boosts while indexing.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your input so far. I found out that my schema or may not have norms enabled for one of the fields, and has it disabled for the other. I've added the schema details to the question, with a couple of extra questions related to that :)

Comment: I tried enabling norms on both queried fields, and that seemed to make no difference whatsoever. This remains unsolved, although I've found a workaround (store the index-time boost value in a field and use it in a sort parameter).

Comment: What means makes no difference weights should change. But you cant expect a value to change ordering. I mean you asked about index time boosts thats the answer. IF the calculation of weights means in your eyes something else thats a different question. The formula is btw described exhaustive in the java docs.

Comment: Yes, `fieldWeight(aoh_dictionary_tids` is different for the results, but the differences are not what I would expect. Some with low boosts rank higher than results with high boost values. Why the difference if not for the boost value? It's supposed to be a boolean match…

Comment: Boost is "only" a multiplicator to the original weight. Look e.g. here for the complete formula: http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html .

Comment: I am afraid my math-chops are insufficient for those formulae, but as I understand it, I should use higher boost values if I want it to determine the sort order of a query like this, because although they all match the query equally well, there's other factors that play into the ranking that will affect the order.

Comment: Exactly but what you may do is to implement a custom similarity("weighting" in a broader sense) to accomplish what you are trying to do.